# How to concatenate a variable with string text for displaying as placeholder of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, placeholder

I have this script for adding new input field when user click on a link with id of `add`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#dyanimc-field').append("<input type='text' name='tag_name[]' value='' class='form-control' id='tagInput' placeholder='Tag name'+i>");
            });
 });
```

Now this works fine and properly adds a new input field but I want the **placeholder** of this input to be showing the value of `i` variable next to the `Tag name` text.

So the inputs would have these placeholder:

[image: capture]

Therefore I tried this `placeholder='Tag name'+i>` but this is wrong because it does not return any `i` variable value!

So how to concatenate a variable with string text for displaying as placeholder of an input correctly?

Comment: _"So how to concatenate a variable with string text"_ - And you haven't found anything in the WWW (or here on SO) on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dyanimc-field').append("<input type='text' name='tag_name[]' value='' class='form-control' id='tagInput' placeholder='Tag name " + i.toString() + "'>");
    });
});
```

Comment: The `.toString()` is unnecessary.

Comment: true, but helps explain what it is doing, at a glance @Andreas